# How to insert records in Big Object through developer console?

Tags: developer-console, insert, big-object

I am creating Big Object through workbench like `Survey__b`. I inserting record through developer console, in this time showing error:

> Variable does not exist.

But i have all variables in the big object. When i highlight these fields(`Question1__c`, `Answer1__c`,`WhatID__c`,`WhatObject__c`) inserting `WhatTime__c` only and get ID. How to insert all fields? could anybody help on this.

### Inserting data:

```
Account a = [ select id, name from account limit 1 ];  
Survey__b survey = new Survey__b();  
survey.WhatID__c = a.id;  
survey.WhatTime__c = System.today() + 1;  
survey.WhatObject__c = 'Account';  
survey.Question1__c = 'What is the rating';  
survey.Answer1__c = '1';  
Database.SaveResult saveResult = database.insertImmediate(survey);  
System.debug( ' success ' + saveResult.isSuccess() + ' ' + saveResult );
```

Comment: which "Variable does not exist." ?

Comment: @
Alexander Berehovskiy, These fields : WhatID__c , WhatObject__c , Question1__c ,Answer1__c

Comment: I THINK you missed one variable.Please try it in anonymous window you will come to know.check debug log if you miss any required field

Comment: @ Annappa PH, I am using these two fields, then successfully inserted. WhatTime__c = DateTime.newInstance(2018, 2, 5), WhatID__c = 'A100'; .. What is the problem of using other fields

Comment: @Alexander Berehovskiy, you have any idea, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission.

I have the same error and it is because of the permission.

Once, check all of the field permission, it works fine.

[image]